# Python код для Dualshok 4

Tags: python, pygame

Как сделать python код который будет передавать данные с гироскопа dualshock 4 в консоль
Геймпад я подключаю к пк по блютуз и работает он через DS4Windows (Эмулирует dualshock)
Гироскоп исправно работает, я пытался сделать код но он считывает только положение правого стика

```
import pygame
import time

pygame.init()

pygame.joystick.init()
joystick = pygame.joystick.Joystick(0)
joystick.init()

try:
    while True:
        pygame.event.get()
    
        x = joystick.get_axis(3)  # Ось X
        z = joystick.get_axis(2)  # Ось Z
    
        print(f"X: {x}, Z: {z}")
    
        time.sleep(0.1)


except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('бб')
finally:
    pygame.quit()
```

Помогите сделать так что бы выводились данные гироскопа